# Piecewise linear function reduces to threshold function?

Tags: neural-network

I was reading a book where piecewise function is defined as 
[image: piecewise linear function]

where varphi is the peicewise function

[image]

It says the special forms of piecewise-linear function is :

1. A linear combiner arises if the linear region of operation is maintained without running into saturation
2. The piecewise-linear function reduces to a threshold function if the amplification factor of the linear region is made infinitely large

I tried to understand no 1 as the function value will rise if the adder output value of NN sticks to this area: ( -.5 to .5 ) :

[image]

not in <-.5 and >.5 region. I don't know if that's correct.
As for no 2, i have no idea what is being implied. A threshold function is presented in the book as :
[image]

What is "amplification factor" and how it behave like threshold function when made infinitively large ?

Comment: I feel very stupid, but it really seems like something is wrong with your first graph to me, in my eyes this is the correct graph: https://i.gyazo.com/16afc119a3d46435578679fd5f8d7118.png. Where the x-asis is `v` and the y-axis is `phi`. Let me guide you: `phi` stays `0` until `v` reaches `-0.5`, then `phi = v` until `+0.5`, then `phi` is `1`.

Comment: in the book the figure is like this. Maybe it has different versions ?

Comment: I don't know... I just drew the graph from the formula you provided. There is no way `phi(v)` can be `0.7` for example... it would make sense if `v*2, 0.5 > v > -0.5`